# What's the difference between the two "What is worldbuilding?" questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What is world building?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25185/what-is-world-building)

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/what-is-worldbuilding

These are two questions that were both asked on Worldbuilding proper asking the same question: what is considered worldbuilding; what is the definition of it? However, I've noticed a few things. Why was the first question closed with 4 downvotes, while the second question, asked more recently, is still open, with 3 upvotes (until I downvoted on it) and 1 favorite? Aren't these both essentially the same question?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is pretty unclear and is just a few broad bullet points.  The second one shows some thought; the asker has a problem and a clear question, albeit also broad.  I also suspect that once the migration to meta was suggested, people who might have downvoted refrained -- this is obviously somebody new to the Stack Exchange network who didn't even know about meta, so people might have just voted to migrate.